# Node.js CPU issue/Optimization

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, sockets, optimization

Me and my friend are making a node.js game, and we have been testing cpu, but after profiling this process called zlib is sucking most of the CPU/RAM

3 clients connected to a game is fine, but when 12~13 players are connected it uses 58% where zlib is using about 30% of this cpu.

```
inclusive      self           name
ticks   total  ticks   total
64775   58.5%  64775   58.5%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
25001   22.6%    224    0.2%  LazyCompile: *callback zlib.js:409
//this one is a different zlib
7435    6.7%     82    0.1%  LazyCompile: ~callback zlib.js:409
```

Is there any way to decrease the cpu usage from this? or is there a reason why it is increasing so much.

I have done some reading and I am told it is from socket.io so here is our section of socket sending most of the data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (u.room == users[i].room && users[i].x + users[i].radius >= u.x - u.screenWidth / 2 - 20 && users[i].x - users[i].radius <= u.x + u.screenWidth / 2 + 20 && users[i].y + users[i].radius >= u.y - u.screenHeight / 2 - 20 && users[i].y - users[i].radius <= u.y + u.screenHeight / 2 + 20) {
        if (users[i].id == u.id) {
            visiblePlayers.push({
                x: users[i].x,
                y: users[i].y,
                angle: users[i].angle,
                hue: users[i].hue,
                radius: users[i].radius,
                squeeze: users[i].squeeze,
                name: users[i].name,
                dead: users[i].dead,
                isPlayer: true,
                kills: users[i].kills
            });
        } else {
            visiblePlayers.push({
                x: users[i].x,
                y: users[i].y,
                angle: users[i].angle,
                hue: users[i].hue,
                radius: users[i].radius,
                squeeze: users[i].squeeze,
                name: users[i].name,
                dead: users[i].dead
            });
        }
        // SEND DYING INFO: (FOR OFFLINE ANIMATION):
        if (users[i].dying) {
            visiblePlayers[visiblePlayers.length - 1].dying = true;
        }
    }
}
var visibleEnergy = [];
for (var i = 0; i < energies.length; i++) {
    if (u.firstSend || (energies[i].updated && energies[i].room == u.room)) {
        var anim = energies[i].animate;
        if (u.firstSend)
            anim = true;
        visibleEnergy.push({
            x: energies[i].x,
            y: energies[i].y,
            radius: energies[i].radius,
            index: i,
            animate: anim,
            hue: energies[i].hue,
            room: energies[i].room
        });
    }
}

// SEND PLAYER UPDATES TO CLIENTS:
sockets[u.id].emit('serverTellPlayerMove', visiblePlayers,
    visibleEnergy);
```

Zlib is one of out problems, but also if there are any other optimisation methods to decrease server CPU.

Extra: the formatting of checking users has been answered in StackExchange at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107922/node-js-cpu-issue. We just need help if there are any methods to decrease the zlib cpu usage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) is a widely used compression library. The most likely reason you're seeing lots of CPU usage there is a lot of compressed network traffic. That's desirable because CPU is generally 'cheaper' than network traffic. Other areas that are likely candidates for heavy zlib usage would be compressed files on disk being loaded through node.js's [`zlib` module](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html), or perhaps if you're doing server-side decompression of PNG images which also commonly [uses zlib](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Compression.html).

If you find the zlib 'tax' is too much for your particular application, perhaps you could offload the decompression to another process. You could use a few node.js services in front of your main server whose purpose is purely to connect to clients. Then have them talk to your server in uncompressed, 'raw' format which your server has an easier time understanding.

You don't mention if this is actually causing you problems yet. I wouldn't necessarily worry about it yet. This kind of single process scalability is a downside of using node.js, and the only solution is to split up your service into smaller parts that can be spread across multiple cores or even multiple servers.

Comment: Thank you, I found out where zlib was being used in the socket. Firstly decreased the data being sent then disabled the socket zlib zipping. it has decreased the server load by 40%, thanks for that infor Alex!